# Quotient of the $n-$th skeleton with the complement of a $n-$cell

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider the $n-$skeleton $K^n$ of a CW-complex and let $f:\overline{D}^n\to K^n$ the attaching map of an $n-$cell, where $\overline{D}^n$ is the closed $n-$dimensional disk. I know that the restriction of f to the interior of the disk is a homeomorphism with its image. What can be said about the homology groups of the space obtained quotienting K^n with the complement of the image of this restriction?

I don't know how to move in these situation. Probably there should be a relation with relative homology groups of the pair given by the "model" of the cell $(\overline{D}^n, \partial\overline{D}^n) $

Any hint on how to proceed?

Comment: The quotient is just homeomorphic to $S^n$ via the obvious map. (It takes a little work to prove this map is a homeomorphism.)

Comment: @EricWofsey that doesn't seem right - for example take a triangle with natural CW structure, and contract an edge (but two vertices aren't identified), then this is like $S^1$ with a double point. (rather than $S^1$). If the image of the boundary $S^{n-1}$ is more complicated, I imagine the quotient may be even weirder?

Comment: @Pig: OP wants to contract the *complement* of an open $n$-cell.

Comment: Oh nvm, thanks!

Comment: No, that map would be constant, since the entire boundary of the disk will end up getting collapsed to a point in the quotient.  It sounds like you are very badly confused about what's going on here; I would suggest actually drawing out some examples (with $n=1$, say) to see what quotient you are taking.

Comment: @EricWofsey My bad, the restriction obviously contracts to a point... Sorry. Maybe I can consider the composition of the projection with the "whole" $f$: in this case I know that the restriction of this last map to the interior of the disk is a homeomorphism, while all the rest is contracted to a point. This gives a homeomorphism of the quotient with the quotient $D^n/S^{n-1}\simeq S^n$. In this way I have that the map induced by $pf$ in homology is an isomorphism between the groups $H_n(D^n, S^{n-1})$ and $\widetilde{H_n} (X) $ where $X$ is the quotient... Is it right or is there some error?

Comment: That's right, except it takes some work to check that your map between the quotient and $D^n/S^{n-1}$ actually is a homeomorphism.  (It's obviously a bijection but you have to check that the topologies are the same.)

Comment: Yes of course, I just wanted to write the outline of the reasoning... By the construction the map should be bijective but also continuous, thanks to the usual theorem of factoring maps into the quotient. To conclude I only have to check that this map is open, for instance, or closed. Thanks!